# Error when Decode h264 file by using FFMPEG with multithreading?

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, decode

I write the code for decoding many .flv video files. Each video file is decoded by a separate thread.
When I try on 1 thread, everything is ok. But when I try on more than 2 threads, it always occurs the error "insufficient thread locking around avcodec_open/close()".

I have searched and I know the functions avcodec_open() and avcodec_close() is not thread safe.
And after that, I putted the mutex locking at anywhere that two that functions are called.

```
lockObj.Lock();
avcodec_open/close();
lockObj.UnLock();
```

But the error "insufficient thread locking around avcodec_open/close()" is still happen.

Someone can tell me the solution?

Many thanks,

T&TGroup

Answer (score 0):

Is `lockObj` the same object in every thread?

The point of the mutex is to stop more than one thread from calling `avcodec_open()` at the same time. The other threads should stop and wait when they get to the `lockObj.Lock()` statement until the first thread calls `lockObj.UnLock()`. This is not possible if each thread has its own `lockObj`.

I have used this method with a QMutex (from Qt), so I know it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, niahnke!
I'm sure that lockObj is same object in every thread because lockObj and all threads were declared in the same file.